# Intersection of a conic and a line

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

Suppose $C=\{x_0^2+x_1^2+x_2^2\}\subset \mathbb{P}^2_{x_0,x_1,x_2}$, and $L=\{a_0x_0+a_1x_1+a_2x_2\}\subset \mathbb{P}^2_{x_0,x_1,x_2}$, I was asked to find the set of coefficients $(a_0,a_1,a_2)$ such that $C$ and $L$ do not intersect at two distinct points. Isn't $C$ only contain the origin in this case? How can I find such coefficients?

Answer (score 0):

The main idea here is that a conic and a line always meet at two points when *counted with multiplicity*. In other words, you are looking for triples of coefficients such that the line meets $C$ with multiplicity two, i.e. is tangent to $C$. This is basically a multivariable calculus exercise (hint: you should get a condition of the form $F = 0$, where $F$ is a homogeneous polynomial in $a_0,a_1,$ and $a_2$).

Comment: So should I just try to solve the set of equations $x_0^2+x_1^2+x_2^2=0$ and $a_0x_0+a_1x_1+a_2x_2=0$ and see when do I have only one solution?

Comment: That might work, but what I am suggesting is that you write down the equation of the tangent line to $C$ at an arbitrary point (which involves partial derivatives of the equation of $C$), which will give you formulas for the $a_i$.

Comment: But then I would get $2x_0=a_0, 2x_1=a_1,2x_2=a_2$, which doesn't really give me any information......

Comment: I'm not certain that those equations are correct, but whatever the correct equations are you can plug them into the equation of the conic to get a quadratic relation among the $a_i$, e.g. if those are correct, $x_i = a_i / 2$ so after plugging in and clearing denominators I get $a_0^2 + a_1^2 + a_2^2 = 0$.